# postgres - inserting a column value as literal 'null'

Tags: postgresql

Using pgadmin, I am trying to import data into a table from a CSV file - as it's a lot faster than running SQL scripts.

I am having problem when one of the column value is `'NULL'`. The problem is that postgres is taking it as `null` where as this should really be `'NULL'`. How can I avoid this?

in other words, the below CSV import fails:

```
my_column
A1B2
NULL  // Postgres fails here because it thinks I am inserting a null into non-nullable column, but it's a text value
```

Thanks,

Comment: What pgAdmin are you using pgAdmin3 or pgAdmin4?  Using pgAdmin4, I cannot reproduce this problem unless I go out of my way to declare that 'NULL' should be interpreted as `NULL`.

Comment: pgadmin4. I got it sorted now by adding \N to check null and ignoring all other columns except the one I wanted.